# How can I safely move the CBB database?

Tags: cloudberry

I want to move the CBB database to the 'data drive' so that it is included in the regular backups.

1) is this possible?
2) if so how can it be done safely?

Is it as simple as taking a copy of the .db file to a new location and then pointing CBB application to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need it? With every backed up file it becomes more and more outdated. If anything happens all you need is to create storage account, pick the same bucket and rebuild the database.
Go to Tools -> Options -> Repository tab -> Synchronize 
CLI:

```
cbb.exe account -l
cbb.exe account -s "accountname"
```

-l  will list all account

To move it:

```
cbb.exe option -databaseLocation path
```

(where "path" is a new repository file destination. As a result, the CBBackup.db file will be moved to the new location.)
Or just click Tools -> Options -> Repository tab -> Shield icon
Make sure that you don't have any running plans.

Comment: you ask a good q. "Why do I need it". I was hoping that working with old copies of DB might speed up the indexing process when performing a backup, but I realise now, after a few trial runs, I guess that the DB gets pretty much rebuilt each time - which when I think about it makes sense.  Thanks!